# Is it possible to allocate memory in MSVC/VC++ at given base?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to allocate memory in MSVC at given base? Or at least force it to allocate memory below the virtual 4GB (i.e. allocate at address that uses 32 bits only) - beside compiling the solution for x86 instead of x64 of course.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What is the use-case?

Comment: According to MSDN you could use `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO` to make all memory be under the 2Gb limit.

Comment: I think you can't do it because when you create a process, operating system assigns an address space to your process. You can only use that assigned memory.
If you try to access, it will cause segmantation fault error. Operating system will warn your process with a signal and if you don't handle that signal, it will terminate your process. 

You can try it by using pointers such as below. Assign its address manually and then try to reach there.

long* ptr = 0xfffffffff
*ptr = 12;

Comment: Great, the LARGEADDRESSAWARE actually did the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN you could use `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO` to make all memory be under the 2Gb limit.

Otherwise if you want both memory under and above the 2Gb limit you could perhaps implement an allocator above the `VirtualAlloc` function.